# Glossary as appendix

Tags: sectioning, glossaries, appendices

I'm using the `glossaries` package to manage my glossary. This works nicely, except that it forces a page break and creates a huge heading saying Glossary that conflicts with the style of my paper somewhat.

Ideally I'd like to stick it in as Appendix A, using the same style for the heading as the Appendix headings, and not messing up the other appendices. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test it right now, but according to section 2.2. of the `glossaries` manual (and assuming a document class whose `\chapter` and `\section` macros at least resemble those of the standard classes), loading

```
\usepackage[section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
```

in the preamble and issuing `\printglossaries` immediately after `\appendix` in the document body should do what you want.

EDIT: Minimal working example (including some speculation about your appendix numbering scheme):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[section,numberedsection=autolabel]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{electrolyte}{name=electrolyte,%
    description={solution able to conduct electric current}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

Some text about \gls{electrolyte}.

\appendix

\chapter*{Appendix}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Appendix}}{\MakeUppercase{Appendix}}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Pretty much works how I want... Except that I was using \section*{} to prepend the word Appendix to the headings. I suppose that's another problem though, or otherwise I'll just stick to just the letters.